# Servlet Parameter Problem if value contains '+'

Tags: servlets

I am sending parameter to servlet using the URL below:

http://localhost:8084/TestWeb/TestServlet?text=k+k

In servlet, I am getting value of "text" parameter as "k k".

I want value of "text" parameter as "k+k".

Answer (score 2):

In a URL, a plus sign is used to indicate a space.  You will probably need to use a hex-encoding for the plus sign (0x2B) to have it treated as plus.

http://localhost:8084/TestWeb/TestServlet?text=k%2Bk

Answer (score 2):

`+` is a special character in http query strings that is used to represent a space character. If you want to pass real + you need to insert it as %2B where 2B is a hexadecimal code for ASCII symbol +. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string?wasRedirected=true for details.